# How do i use HibernateTemplate.findByNamedParam()?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm, hql

HI, i am trying to use the above spring hibernate temnplate method do a simple query based on a specific ID from the database but the problem is that the query doesnt replace the ":" character from the sql string below into the value contained in "id".

i thought that this method replaces ":" with the given parameter i set in the method bit it doesnt?

Code is below:

```
private static final String SQL_GET_FILE = "select new FileObject(filename, size, id, type, file) from FileObject where id = : limit 1";

FileObject file = (FileObject) hbTemplate.findByNamedParam(SQL_GET_FILE, "id", id);
```

//File object POJO:

```
package com.kc.models;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.hibernate.Hibernate;

public class FileObject {

    private String filename;
    private String type;
    private double size;
    private Blob file;
    private int id;

    public FileObject() {

    }

    public FileObject(String name, double size, int id, String type) {
        this.filename = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.size = size;
        this.id = id;

    }

    public FileObject(String name, double size, int id, String type, Blob file) {
        this.filename = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.size = size;
        this.id = id;
        this.file = file;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String fileName) {
        this.filename = fileName;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public double getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(double size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public Blob getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(Blob file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

}
```

The exception i get is basically this:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 1 near line 1, column 104 [select new FileObject(filename, size, id, type, file) from com.kc.models.FileObject where id = : limit 1]
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:31)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:24)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:59)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:258)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:157)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
    org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
    org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$31.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:949)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByNamedParam(HibernateTemplate.java:947)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByNamedParam(HibernateTemplate.java:938)
    com.kc.models.DbFileHelper.getFile(DbFileHelper.java:81)
    com.kc.models.FileHelper.getFileFromDb(FileHelper.java:195)
    com.kc.Controllers.DownloadAppController.handle(DownloadAppController.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractCommandController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractCommandController.java:84)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Now i have temporarily done a quick fix by simply  doing the above

```
private static final String SQL_GET_FILE = "select new FileObject(filename, size, id, type, file) from FileObject where id = ";


List<FileObject>  file =  hbTemplate.find(SQL_GET_FILE+id);
```

But i dont like the idea of joining a query string with +.

it would get tedius if i have a sql looking something like this:

```
SQL_GET_FILE = "select new FileObject(filename, size, id, type, file) 
  from FileObject where id = 10 && size < 1000 && type = jpg";
```

cheers in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should give the parameter a name, not just a colon:

```
where id = :id
```

Also, don't use `LIMIT` - use `template.setMaxResults()`

Actually, I would advise for using the hibernate `Session` directly - the `HibernateTemplate` is something that the guys at Hibernate criticize a lot - [see here the comments by Gaving King](https://houseofhaug.wordpress.com/2005/08/12/hibernate-hates-spring/).

You can still use `HibernateTemplate`, but for features (like `setFirstResult(..)`) you can use the `Session`.

Finally, I think using `EntityManager` is the best choice. Spring offers very good JPA integration as well.

Comment: OOO ok i will try that:

private static final String SQL_GET_FILE = "select new FileObject(filename, size, id, type, file) from FileObject where id = :id limit 1";

Comment: Diddnt work. i got this exception:

org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: limit near line 1, column 100 [select new FileObject(filename, size, id, type, file) from com.kc.models.FileObject where id = :id limit 1]

Comment: what object is "query"? i write my sql statements in a string and use the FindByNameParam method to construct my query using a hibernate template

Comment: Cool ok thanks i will try that. Why do people critisise the HibernameTemplate. its pretty straight forward to use and powerful.

Comment: interesting blog that is that seems to be that the guys from hibernate are just pissed off with spring and how many agree that hibernateTemplate is fine the way it is.

Comment: well, almost. Gavin has some fair points though. To be fair, I've used HibernateTemplate in only one project, and everywhere else I've used either Session or EntityManager

Comment: To use a session do i just use this directly:

Comment: <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1"></property>
  <property name="mappingResources">
   <list>
    <value>FileObject.hbm.xml</value>
    <value>MobileApp.hbm.xml</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

Comment: No need to create a template based on that SessionFactory?